# Remove language pack from Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, language

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing the Windows XP interface from French to English](https://superuser.com/questions/35933/window-xp-operation-system-french-to-english-language)

A friend has purchased a netbook with a localized XP edition (Hebrew). Now he wants to have the English version of XP on it.

Is there a way to uninstall the language pack and go back to English or something like that?

Comment: I would refer you to this question, it was from French to English, it's the same process : http://superuser.com/questions/35933/window-xp-operation-system-french-to-english-language

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it. You can only install OS language packs on a English system. It is so by design.
So the only option would be to reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what specific version, but I'm quite sure that the answer is "no" unless your friend has the professional edition (?).

Answer (score 0):

To remove:

> Control Panel/Regional and Language
>   options/Languages/Details/Remove

Don't forget to first add the english language pack and try it out, because my real impression is that you can't convert a Hebrew XP installation into English without reinstalling Windows. Meaning that the language pack will only allow you to type in English, while all the applications already installed will still use a Hebrew user interface.