# Restoring Windows XP language to original

Tags: windows-xp, language

I installed the Arabic language pack in Windows XP which configured the PC to be in Arabic.

However I now want to get back to original setting (French language in my case) but don't know how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the language pack by chance?  Just replace English with French - http://superuser.com/questions/35933/window-xp-operation-system-french-to-english-language

Answer (score 0):

> To uninstall a language pack (a.k.a. MUI) from Windows XP you will
>   need to find the original MUI installation files. Within those files
>   there is one called "MUISETUP.exe". Run that file and de-select all
>   the languages you want to remove from your system.

[Source of Information](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/uninstall-language-packs-windows-xp-t3736110.html)

You may also be able to change the language in Regional and Language Options in Control Panel.